# Show divider line in between menu items of native menu

Tags: android, menuitem, divider, overflow-menu

[image: Show a horizontal divider in between menu titles]

I want to edit horizontal line between menu titles ,  i refer many solutions but not any of them able to find my solution.Please help me to find solution for this

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:icon="@mipmap/contact"
        android:title="Contact Us"
        android:checked="true"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/latest"
        android:icon="@mipmap/latest"
        android:title="Latest ***"
        android:checked="true"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/grp3" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/my_picture"
    android:icon="@mipmap/my_picture"
    android:checked="true"
    android:title="My *** Pictures"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you are using LinearLayout for creating the Menu items. Then just add attr divider to it.

Answer (score 0):

customize you AppTheme. try this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--- Customize popmenu -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/popup</item>
</style>

<style name="popup" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         <group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
        </group>
 <group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
                android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
        </group>
    </menu>
```

try this

Comment: It just creates a round at right side of title , sorry but not working

Comment: take every item in different group surely it will work

Comment: hello hasmukh i took different group for different item but the result you can see over this http://imgh.us/rsz_device-2017-04-07-155743.png

Comment: may be your divider color have to be change in style or theme

Comment: thank you hasmukh but there is no such thing in style that would help in this